# Can I somehow access a specific element from json in Python?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a simple discord bot minigame and I can't figure out how to check if someone has an item named laptop.

Here's the json file:
`{"user-id-example": {"wallet": 999, "bank": 999, "bag": [{"item": "watch", "amount": 999}, {"item": "laptop", "amount": 999}]}}`

Here's my working command:

```
@client.command 
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user) 
async def work(ctx):
     await open_account(ctx.author)

     user = ctx.author
     users = await get_bank_data()

     earnings = random.randrange(750, 1000)

     users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

     with open ("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
          json.dump(f)

     await ctx.send(f"You earned {earnings}!")
```

I just want to make the 'work' command usable only for people who have a laptop

Comment: `if any(x['item'] == 'laptop' for x in data['bag']):`?

Comment: `json.dump()` needs a second argument, the data that you're writing to the file.

Comment: Thank you, it works. And yeah, it was a mistake in that ```json.dump()```

Comment: `if ('item', 'laptop') in data['bag'].items():`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question:

```
if any(x['item'] == 'laptop' for x in data['user-id-example']['bag']):
    print("User has a laptop in his bag!")
```

You have to replace the 'user-id-example' with the actual user id by replacing `data['user-id-example']['bag']` with `data[str(user.id)]['bag']`.

I might be wrong but I think, that `json.dump()` needs a second argument, when dumping to a file. So it has to be something like that:

```
with open ("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(data, f)
```

You have to replace the `data` object with you JSON object, which I guess is in your case called `users`

Comment: Thank you! It's everything I wanted!